# Unable to connect to Pentaho data integration repository

Tags: repository, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I have set up Pentaho data integration 7.0 on an AWS server. But when I try to go to connect repository, in order to create a new repository, but my PDI 7.0 doesnt even show the option to connect to repository.

[image]

I am not getting any idea, how to get this option working ?

Comment: Have you tried the `Connect` button at the top-right corner of Spoon window?

Comment: Yes, i did try and got going. thanks !